# Android: Some notification can be cancelled and some not

Tags: android, android-notifications

I write an android app to cancel all notifications.

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "package:" + sbn.getPackageName());
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "tag:" + sbn.getTag());
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "id:" + sbn.getId());
        cancelAllNotifications();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "remove package:" + sbn.getPackageName());
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "remove tag:" + sbn.getTag());
        Log.d("NotificationListener", "remove id:" + sbn.getId());
    }
}
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service android:name=".NotificationListener"
        android:label="@string/service_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I can cancel the following packages notifications:

```
05-19 10:25:22.422  1289  1307 D NotificationListener : remove package:com.android.providers.downloads
05-19 10:25:22.422  1289  1307 D NotificationListener : remove tag:1:com.android.vending
05-19 10:25:22.422  1289  1307 D NotificationListener : remove id:0
```

But I cannot cancel the following packages notifications:

```
05-19 10:25:20.492  1289  1306 D NotificationListener : package:com.android.settings
05-19 10:25:20.492  1289  1306 D NotificationListener : tag:null
05-19 10:25:20.492  1289  1306 D NotificationListener : id:2130837807
```

Anyone knows why?

Thanks in advance.

Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notifications cannot be cancelled because they have been set with `FLAG_NO_CLEAR`. Check the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR).